# Calculating group Standard Deviation in R, when you have groups with multiple data

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I am working with R, and I am trying to calculate my standard deviation correctly.

My data look like this:

```
Target     category       wordproduced       wordValue
wall         A                  home           .003
wall         A                  table          .005
widnow       A                  cow            .015
window       B                  backyard       .012
friend       B                  dog            .018
friend       B                  chance         .088
friend       B                  spoon          .002
big          C                  country        .009
big          C                  pen            .015
big          C                  pub            .012
money        C                  palace         .078
rail         C                  wood           .026
rail         C                  ferrari        .030
rail         C                  car            .062
science      D                  phone          .007
science      D                  laboratory     .009
science      D                  side           .019
water        D                  ocean          .013
water        D                  river          .020
```

So, I have four categories (A,B,C,D), and I have a total of 8 words. Each word belongs to a category.

So, if I want to calculate the mean value of wordsproduced by the target words I write a code like this ....

```
mydata %>%
 group_by(category) %>%
 summarise(TargetN = length(unique(Taregt)), 
           wPoroducedN = length(wordsproduced),
           meanW = wProducedN/TargetN)
```

If I calculate the mean with the mean() function, it gets the wrong mean because it calculates every word in the target. For example, category A has only 2 unique words but 3 in total. So, I need to calculate my mean diving by two. The above code solves this. But when calculating the SD I get lots of wrong answers or NA's.

For example, I tried this...

```
mydata %>%
 group_by(category) %>%
 summarise(TargetN = length(unique(Taregt)), 
           wPoroducedN = length(wordsproduced),
           meanW = wProducedN/TargetN, 
           SD = sd(length(wordproduced)))
```

In here, I get NA., and with other codes, I get 0 o the exact amount of unique target, etc..

How should I calculate my SD?

adding a reproducible data.... **categories are changed for numbers; instead, os ABCD is 123 (only three)

```
newDat <- structure(list(Target = c(
  "permit",
  "confusion",
  "presion",
  "transanction",
  "sorprise",
  "same",
  "agony",
  "prime",
  "suffer",
  "affect",
  "car",
  "neglect",
  "intern",
  "explore",
  "image",
  "pension",
  "amature",
  "terrified",
  "importance",
  "deal",
  "replace",
  "euforic",
  "optimist",
  "return",
  "inmerse",
  "doll",
  "actor",
  "singular",
  "desctruction",
  "dispute",
  "tremor",
  "profesional",
  "redem",
  "euforic",
  "pen",
  "pause",
  "cultive",
  "center",
  "cheer",
  "slace",
  "recess",
  "apple",
  "introduction",
  "despicable",
  "offense",
  "inteligent",
  "hope",
  "contender",
  "stress",
  "disgust"
), Category = c(
  "3",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "2",
  "2",
  "2",
  "2",
  "2",
  "1",
  "1",
  "2",
  "2",
  "1",
  "1",
  "2",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "2",
  "1",
  "1",
  "3",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "1",
  "3",
  "1",
  "2",
  "2",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "1",
  "2",
  "1",
  "3",
  "1",
  "1"
), wordproduced = c(
  "liberty",
  "intense",
  "sad",
  "serenity",
  "afraid",
  "sadness",
  "hurt",
  "freedom",
  "depress",
  "feeling",
  "love",
  "positive",
  "river",
  "palace",
  "ilusion",
  "stress",
  "aliviated",
  "violence",
  "presion",
  "damage",
  "hate",
  "happy",
  "dwindle",
  "spoon",
  "kitchen",
  "dog",
  "backyard",
  "alone",
  "cat",
  "confidence",
  "fear",
  "moving",
  "house",
  "ocean",
  "territory",
  "continent",
  "sky",
  "rainbow",
  "approach",
  "law",
  "good",
  "school",
  "science",
  "land",
  "laboratory",
  "engage",
  "destiny",
  "voice",
  "arange",
  "infertile"
), wordValue = c(
  0.10,
  0.09,
  0.01,
  0.1,
  0.046,
  0.316,
  0.12,
  0.03,
  0.03,
  0.02,
  0.46,
  0.19,
  0.26,
  0.070,
  0.040,
  0.01,
  0.025,
  0.03,
  0.05,
  0.089,
  0.075,
  0.03,
  0.067,
  0.04,
  0.04,
  0.1,
  0.068,
  0.055,
  0.17,
  0.075,
  0.535,
  0.06,
  0.1,
  0.12,
  0.04,
  0.08,
  0.036,
  0.1,
  0.05,
  0.050,
  0.07,
  0.05,
  0.8,
  0.05,
  0.06,
  0.08,
  0.055,
  0.04,
  0.12,
  0.049
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df",
                                       "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I just did. Thanks for the recomendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit for sample data added:

While I'm not sure what you're trying to do, I can tell you are getting `NA`s there because you're asking for the SD of one number...which doesn't make sense. Ie...`length(wordsproduced)` will give you one number for the length, one category at a time.

I assume you want the SD of the number of `wordsproduced` per `target`, for each `category`.

So, you've calculated the mean `wordsproduced` per `Target` per `category`, as such:

```
newDat_summary <- newDat %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(TargetN = length(unique(Target)), 
            wProducedN = length(wordproduced),
            meanW = wProducedN/TargetN)

> newDat_summary
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Category TargetN wProducedN meanW
  <chr>      <int>      <int> <dbl>
1 1             31         32  1.03
2 2             13         13  1   
3 3              5          5  1
```

For the SD, we need to first find the number of `wordsproduced` per `Target` in each `category` separately:

```
newDat_summary2 <- newDat %>%
  group_by(Category, Target) %>%
  summarise(TargetN = length(unique(Target)), 
            wProducedN = length(wordproduced))

> newDat_summary2
# A tibble: 49 x 4
# Groups:   Category [3]
   Category Target       TargetN wProducedN
   <chr>    <chr>          <int>      <int>
 1 1        agony              1          1
 2 1        amature            1          1
 3 1        apple              1          1
 4 1        cheer              1          1
 5 1        confusion          1          1
 6 1        cultive            1          1
 7 1        deal               1          1
 8 1        desctruction       1          1
 9 1        despicable         1          1
10 1        disgust            1          1
# ... with 39 more rows
```

Now that we have multiple values we can find the SD between them:

```
newDat_summary3 <- newDat_summary2 %>% group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(SD = sd(wProducedN))

> mydata_summary3
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  category    SD
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 A        0.707
2 B        1.41 
3 C        1.15 
4 D        0.707
```

And then we join that with the means per `Target` per `category`:

```
newDat_summary <- merge(newDat_summary,newDat_summary3,by = "Category")

> newDat_summary
  Category TargetN wProducedN    meanW        SD
1        1      31         32 1.032258 0.1796053
2        2      13         13 1.000000 0.0000000
3        3       5          5 1.000000 0.0000000
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.